# Visualize PCA, train or test?

Tags: python, pca, fitting, numpy

I am new to PCA and have a question about visualization when it comes to fitting and transposing. I have two data, which are train and test.  Here are four methods:

```
# Method 1)
pca = myPCA(n_components = 5) # Conduct myPCA with 5 principal components.
pca.fit(X_train) # Calculate 5 principal components on the training dataset
X_train_pca = pca.transform(X_train)

# Method 2)
pca = myPCA(n_components = 5) # Conduct myPCA with 5 principal components.
pca.fit(X_test)
X_test_pca = pca.transform(X_test)

# Method 3)
pca = myPCA(n_components = 5) # Conduct myPCA with 5 principal components.
pca.fit(X_train)
X_test_pca = pca.transform(X_train)

# Method 4)
pca = myPCA(n_components = 5) # Conduct myPCA with 5 principal components.
pca.fit(X_train)
X_test_pca = pca.transform(X_test)
```

**My question is: Which way is the right way to use PCA for visualization? Method 1)? Method2)? 3)? Or 4)?**  Although the PCA's tutorial clearly says it needs to be run on the test data, however, it seems that I could not write the right method for this.

Here is my code:

```
class myPCA():
"""
Principal Component Analysis (A Linear Dimension Reduction Method).
"""

def __init__(self, n_components = 2):
    """
    Conduct myPCA with 2 principal components(the principal and orthogonal modes of variation).
    """
    self.n_c = n_components


def fit(self,X):
    """
    The procedure of computing the covariance matrix.
    """
    cov_mat = np.cov(X.T) # Covariance matrix
    eig_val, eig_vec = np.linalg.eigh(cov_mat) # Eigen-values and orthogonal eigen-vectors in ascending order.
    eig_val = np.flip(eig_val) # Reverse the order, now it is descending.
    eig_vec = np.flip(eig_vec,axis=1) # reverse the order
    self.eig_values = eig_val[:self.n_c] # select the top eigen-vals
    self.principle_components = eig_vec[:,:self.n_c] # select the top eigen-vecs
    self.variance_ratio = self.eig_values/eig_val.sum() # variance explained by each PC

def transform(self,X):
    """
    Compute the score matrix.
    """
    return np.matmul(X-X.mean(axis = 0),self.principle_components) #project the data (centered) on PCs
```

Visualization Code(still not sure whether to use X_train or X_test below):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
figure = plt.figure(dpi=100)
plt.scatter(X_test_pca[:, 0], X_test_pca[:, 1],c=y_test, s=15,edgecolor='none', alpha=0.5,cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('tab10', 10))
plt.xlabel('component 1')
plt.ylabel('component 2')
plt.colorbar();
```

Comment: Thanks. I still don't really understand your question. What "PCA introduction"?  Are you looking at a tutorial somewhere? The title refers to visualizing, but that doesn't show up anywhere in the text. More generally, this is bereft of context; what are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand the question, because you appear to be comparing a method to itself: the *only* things that differ are the (completely irrelevant) names you give to two data subsets in the code. Maybe there are some typographical errors in your initial code blocks?

Comment: FWIW, I'm 90% sure you should do whatever it is you're trying to do on the training set.

Comment: @gung Another way to put it: whatever data you use to fit the PCA is the training set, no matter what you happen to name it in your code!

Comment: Thank you! Thank you all for the help! What about the visualization part? Should I use X_test and y_test instead of X_train and y_train?

Comment: Could you describe *what* you want to visualize?